# mybaties Type conversion at selection

Tags: oracle, mybatis, amazon-rds, spring-mybatis

I am using mybaties 3.2.6 with AWS Oracle RDS in my project. For one table selection, from table I am getting TimeStamp but at object side I have String. Until now I was using TO_CHAR to convert from timeStamp(JDBC side) to String(Java side) something like this..

```
SELECT SESSION_ID,
      ct.MEMBER_ID as MEMBER_ID  ,
      ct.KO_MEMBER_ID as KO_MEMBER_ID, 
      ct.KO_MEMBER_NAME as KO_MEMBER_NAME, 
      ct.REASON as REASON, 
      TO_CHAR(ct.TICKET_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as TICKET_DTM, 
      ct.DATA_TYPE as DATA_TYPE  
      FROM TICKET ct
      WHERE id=#{Id}
      fetch first 300 rows only
```

But to avoid the DB Function binding issue I do not want to use TO_CHAR function any more. Can I do something at Java end/mybaties end for that,  like CustomTypeHandler or something like that? At insertion time I am using CustomTypeHandler  with java type and Jdbc type notation like ...

```
#{birthday,jdbcType=DATE,javaType=java.lang.String,typeHandler=StringDateTypeHandler}
```

This is working properly for insertion fro type conversion...

Is there something which can help me in type conversion at the time of selection also like we have for insertion?

Comment: Possible solution, change the Java type from String to a propper type...

Comment: :-) :-) :-)   Thanks for your suggestion .....

Answer (score 0):

You [can specify](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps) `typeHandler` in the result map for your type.

If you do not use result map for your query you would need to introduce it by specifying `resultMap` attribute in `select` like this:

```
 <select id="getTickets" resultMap="ticketResultMap">
    ... you query goes here
 </select>
```

Also add `resultMap` definition like this:

```
<resultMap id="ticketResultMap" type="Ticket">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="yourDateColumn" column="TICKET_DTM" 
        typeHandler="StringDateTypeHandler"/>
    <!-- other fields mappings or use autoMapping="true" -->
</resultMap>
```